# missing operand after `homework1' - Makefile

Tags: makefile

I keep getting an error message that says "diff: missing operand after `homework1'", but I have included a bash file.  Can someone take a look at my makefile and give me a hint on how to fix it? Thanks!

```
#
#  $RCSfile$
#  $Revision$
#  $Author$
#  $Date$
#  $Log$
#

CC=gcc
DEBUG=-g
CFLAGS=#(DEBUG) -Wall -Wshadow -Wunreachable-code -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement
PROGS=homework1 

all: $(PROGS) test

homework1: homework1.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o homework1 homework1.o

homework1.o: homework1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c homework1.c

test:   *
    diff $(PROGS) $(example.bash) || exit 0

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) *.o *~
```

Answer (score 0):

You've referenced a make variable `$(example.bash)` but there is no variable `example.bash` set in your makefile.  Did you mean the file `example.bash`?  You shouldn't use make variable syntax, if that's true:

```
test:   *
        diff $(PROGS) example.bash || exit 0
```

(why do you have `*` as a prerequisite here?  That doesn't seem useful)

Comment: Alternatively, if you are executing the bash script, use `$$` because make thinks it is a variable. `$$` escapes the `$` character, letting your shell execute the script.

Comment: @MadScientist: I tried it in a few different ways: "example.bash", $$(example.bash), or $$example.bash. It says that "make: *** No rule to make target `diff', needed by `test'.  Stop.".  What should I do?

Comment: What I want to do is to compare the output of $(PROGS) and example.bash

Comment: That's a totally different problem; it looks like you removed the newline after the `test:` target and now make thinks that the `diff` command is a prerequisite.  You need a newline.  Also your original question was very unclear about what you wanted to do: given your subsequent comments it seems something like Chrono's answer will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the output of two commands using `diff`, you need the output of at least one of those two commands redirected to a file while the output of another command is piped to the input stream of `diff`. Here is an example that replaces `$(PROGS)` with its output file:

```
./$(PROGS) > progs_output
bash example.bash | diff progs_output - || exit 0
```

It executes the value of `$(PROGS)`, sending its output to a file called `progs_output`. Then the bash script is executed, with its output piped to the standard input stream of the `diff` utility, which compares `progs_output` with the stuff coming from its standard input stream. Everything else is your doing. Why would you use exit 0 though? If the test fails, wouldn't you want make to tell you?

Also, what's with the asterisk (*) as a prerequisite for the `test` target?